# Rendering an R Markdown document as a PDF file (output error)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I know this question/error might bit a bit vague but I'm not sure where to start looking to fix this one. I wish to output a file as a pdf but get the following error;

[image]

I have tried outputting the file with almost nothing on just to test that works (no code, no special characters etc) but still no joy. The file does output as a HTML though which I don't really understand

When testing with almost nothing on the document;

[image]

test.log and YAML (test.log might not be correct here)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the "almost nothing" code?

Without seeing it, my money would be on tables/ figures/ text exceeding the bounds of Latex's page dimensions as this is the main reason I find when I've got this error and HTML export still works.

Edited to add:

I've run:

```
---   
output:
      pdf_document: default   
--- 
## R Markdown
This is an R Markdown Document
```

which worked fine for me on a clean install of R and RStudio. This suggests the issue is with the latex compiler or environment rather than the markdown code.

Comment: Yeh sure, i'll add a pic to the question, but its literally just the title and one like of text as a test, no table, plots or code included and still having the same error. Think i had similar before due to special characters hence testing with minimal text

Comment: Oh shoot, that is minimal! Can you include the test.log and the YAML preamble? Maybe there's a clue there.

Comment: How do I do those? (sorry, had a google and an none the wiser)

Comment: When you knit the file to create a pdf a *.log file will be created in the desired destination so you should find a file called test.log in the location you tried to make the pdf into. The YAML is usually at the top of a markdown file and can look like 
`---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
output: pdf_document
---`

Comment: Ok, not sure i have the test.log part correct but i'll add both to the question

Comment: So I've just knit the following code as a PDF and it's working fine for me.  

`---  
output:   
  pdf_document: default  
---  
## R Markdown  
  
This is an R Markdown Document`

This suggests it's to do with your version of the latex compiler. Have you looked at the URL mentioned in the error message?

Comment: How did you install LaTeX on your system? Did you use TinyTeX or something else (TexLive, MikTeX)?